# XDrawString incorrect encoding

Tags: c++, gcc, x11, xlib

I want to display cyrillic symbols with `XDrawString()`, but on screen they are shown in wrong encoding.

I have installed `xfonts-cyrillic` in my system (ubuntu 14.04), but still any font from `xlsfonts` list shows wrong result.

My code (main.cpp):

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int, char**)
{
    Display *d = XOpenDisplay(0);
    Window r = DefaultRootWindow(d);
    Window w = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, r, 0, 0, 256, 256, 0, 0, 0xffffff);
    GC gc = DefaultGC(d, 0);

    XMapRaised(d, w);
    XSelectInput(d, w, ExposureMask);

    Font font = XLoadFont(d, "9x15-cyrillic");
    XSetFont(d, gc, font);

    const char *msg = "тут текст"; // cyrillic symbols

    while (1)
    {
        XEvent e;
        XNextEvent(d, &e);
        XDrawString(d, w, gc, 16, 16, msg, (int) strlen(msg));
    }
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 main.cpp -L/usr/lib/X11 -lX11 -o output
```

My result is:

[image]

Why in result window text is in wrong encoding? What I'm missing?

Answer (score 9):

X11 predates Unicode by several millennia (in Internet years). Your program probably uses UTF-8, and X11 by default does not. Try [Xutf8DrawString](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xutf8drawstring).

Alternatively, figure out which encodings your fonts use (xlsfonts will tell you, because the encoding is a part of XLFD, but it looks like KOI8-R to me) and use that encoding for your string.

It should be noted that real programs rarely use server-side fonts these days. See [this](https://www.x.org/wiki/guide/fonts/#index2h2) for more info.